# Memory leak si new lanza una excepción

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy tratando de entender la garantía de excepción y cómo garantizar que la memoria sea liberada en caso de producirse una excepción en la copia o en la asignación de memoria.

Tomando el siguiente ejemplo minimalista de un vector, intento que se produzca una excepción del tipo `bad_alloc` al reservar con `new` para ver si la memoria reservada previamente se libera.

Entiendo que de producirse una excepción como en el ejemplo tendría una fuga de memoria. ¿Es esto correcto? y de ser correcto, si pongo el new dentro de otro bloque try catch y relanzo la excepción (como en el código comentado como "alternativa"), ¿seguiría teniendo una fuga de memoria y una garantía fuerte de excepción?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int force_exception= 0;

template<typename T>
   class Vector {
      T* v_,
      * space_,
      * last_;
   public:
        Vector()
            : v_{new T{}}, space_{v_}, last_{v_} { }

        ~Vector() {
            delete[] v_;
        }
        size_t size() const {
            return last_ - space_;
        }
        void push_back(T const& val)
        {
            if (space_ == last_) {
                std::size_t sz = size();
                size_t newSize = (sz == 0)? 6 : 6*sz;
                if (++force_exception > 1) {
                    newSize = 99999999999999;
                }
                T* newBlock = new T[newSize]; // si new lanza una excepción...
                // alternativa:
                // T* newBlock = nullptr;
                // try {
                //     newBlock = new T[newSize];
                // }catch(...) {
                //     delete []v_;
                //     throw;
                // }
                try { 
                    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
                        newBlock[i] = v_[i];
                    }
                catch (...) {
                    delete[] newBlock;
                    throw;
                }
                delete[] v_;
                v_ = newBlock;
                space_ = newBlock + sz;
                last_ = newBlock + newSize;
            }
            *space_ = val;
            ++space_;
        }
   };

int main() {

    Vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0;i < 20; i++)
        v.push_back(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me cuesta un poco seguir tu razonamiento, no estoy seguro si esto que te voy a decir te sirve o ya lo sabías.

C++ usa dos tipos principales de asignación de memoria: automática y dinámica.  `new` usa asignación dinámica, lo que significa que el programador es responsable de la liberación de memoria.  C++ no libera automáticamente nada que haya sido asignado de forma dinámica: nada que se haya asignado con `new`.

En caso de excepción atrapada con `catch`, en ese bloque tu código debería liberar lo que haya que liberar.

Otra cosa.  En el constructor estás asignando memoria para `v_` con `new`, y en el destructor usás `delete[] v_` .  Esto resulta en un comportamiento indefinido.  new y delete deben ser coherentes sobre el mismo puntero.  Hay que usar `new` y `delete`, o `new[]` y `delete[]`.  Porque `new[]` toma nota de la cantidad de elementos asignados para ese puntero, para luego liberarlos con `delete[]`.  Esa cantidad queda asociada al puntero, no a la variable.

Tu código puede tener pérdida de memoria (memory leak) al eliminar v_ la primera vez.  Digo "puede", porque el comportamiento es indefinido y depende de la implementación.

Nota sobre coherencia, para otros que lean esta respuesta: las buenas prácticas dictan que el código se programa para que sea legible por un programador, no es suficiente que funcione solamente.